# Accessing root folder in yeoman project gives 404, but bower_components is not

Tags: angularjs, yeoman, bower, yeoman-generator, yeoman-generator-angular

I've just created  web project using yeoman angular generator. I noticed bower_components is in root folder. I want to put other components that is not installed using bower into not_bower_components folder (also in root folder). The problem is that it gives me 404 when i run grunt serve, but all files in bower_components do not return 404. How can i fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Gruntfile generated by angular generator uses [`connect`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/connect) for the http server, the generator also attaches a plugin to the server called [`livereload`](https://github.com/intesso/connect-livereload) which magically injects new code or reloads the page (depending on the extension of the file modified), [these](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-angular/blob/master/templates/common/root/_Gruntfile.js#L87-L105) are the defaults options of the `Gruntfile.js` file, I think you have to update the middleware function to also consider your `not_bower_components` folder:

```
livereload: {
  options: {
    open: true,
    middleware: function (connect) {
      return [
        connect.static('.tmp'),
        connect().use(
          '/bower_components',
          connect.static('./bower_components')
        ),
        connect().use(
          '/not_bower_components',
          connect.static('./not_bower_components')
        ),
        connect().use(
          '/app/styles',
          connect.static('./app/styles')
        ),
        connect.static(appConfig.app)
      ];
    }
  }
}
```